# who is kind? vs who is a kind person?

Tags: relative-pronouns, relative-adverbs

I know that these sentences are right:

- Where is it?
- How are you?
- How big is it?
- Where are you from?

But I am confused about these sentences... so I want you to tell me which one is right. If the other one is wrong, please let me know the reason.

---

1. - I know the place where is good.
   - I know where is a good place.
   - I know where a good place is.

---

2. - I know the person who is kind.
   - I know who is kind.

---

3. - I know when is the best time for you.
   - I know when the best time for you.

---

4. - When is good for you?
   - When is the best time for you?

---

5. - Where is good for you?
   - Where is the best place for you?

---

6. - I don't know which is good.
   - I don't know which place is good.

---

7. - Who is kind?
   - Who is better?
   - What is good for you?

Comment: Please learn to use capital letters at the beginning of sentences. Also, the first-person singular pronoun is **I** not **i** (i.e. capital letter).

Answer (score 2):

1. "I know a good place".

---

2. "I know a/the kind person".

---

3. "I know the best time for you".

---

4. Both are correct!

---

5. Both are correct!

---

6. "I don't know which is better". Or, "I don't know which place is best".

---

7. Without context, determining what you mean is impossible.

Note that these questions are all very short and ambiguous. Depending on the specific scenario, the questions could vary by a lot.

Comment: thanks a lot~ I wnat to know more about this..as you said that number 4 is right. then, is it right to say this 1.I don't know where is good for you. 2.I know where it is. 3. i know where is the best place for you. 4. i know what is good for you.

Comment: @Sunny You should probably just ask a second question.

Comment: I mean... I am learning grammaer of "relative pronounce" .so.. i am not looking for the best sentence to say in each situation. I want to know if each sentence is possible or not. If it is right to say or write, I also want to know how it sounds like... "formal" or "informal" or "we can use it in written English like this...

Comment: Then you should ask another question about *relative pronouns*, using your specific examples, @Sunny

Comment: so I want to know if thoses sentences are possible to use~

Comment: @Sunny In case I wasn't clear, I mean posting another question on this site, *not right here in the comments.*